# adding a cover page to a csv/excel file in python

Tags: python, mysql, eclipse, csv

I am trying to add a cover page to a csv file in python which would display like the general information such as the date and name. My program currently exports mysql data to a csv file in python. When I open the csv, its an excel file. I am trying to add a cover page to this excel file which is in the csv format. Could you give me some ideas as to how I could go about doing this?

Comment: A `.csv` is intentionally a *machine-readable* format. And it consists of rows and columns. There are no document sections of the sort you get in a human-readable document, no headers (other than, optionally, the names of the columns), no record types. If you have metadata like date and name associated with the file, either you cram it into the filename, or create columns for it in your `.csv` file, and tack those columns onto the first row (or every row, it doesn't matter much.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a cover page to a CSV file.

CSV is short for "Comma-separated values". It is defined to just be values separated by commas and nothing else. [Wikipedia states that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Specification):

> RFC 4180 proposes a specification for the CSV format, and this is the
>   definition commonly used. However, in popular usage "CSV" is not a
>   single, well-defined format. As a result, in practice the term "CSV"
>   might refer to any file that:
>
> 1. is plain text using a character set such as ASCII, various Unicode character sets (e.g. UTF-8), EBCDIC, or Shift JIS,
> 2. consists of records (typically one record per line),
> 3. with the records divided into fields separated by delimiters (typically a single reserved character such as comma, semicolon, or
>      tab; sometimes the delimiter may include optional spaces),
> 4. where every record has the same sequence of fields.

This assertion is important for any application which wants to read the file. How would an application deal with weird unexpected data in some proprietary format?

You can, however, invent your own proprietary format, which only you know how to read. This could include data for a cover (as an image, pdf, latex or something else) and the data for your CSV. But this would be quite an undertaking and there are a million ways to approach this problem. The scope on how to implement such a thing is beyond the scope of stackoverflow. Try [breaking down your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it).